# Overwriting vs. adding to the end of read csv files in c++

Tags: c++, csv

I am trying to write a program in which I read and write to already created csv files.  Some of them are overwrited with new data while others are simply added to the end of the file.  I open the files using:

```
ifstream file;
file.open("")
```

then i read the file and do necessary calculations.  I just dont know how to write back to this file in the two ways i need.  Im relatively new to programming so the simplest answer would be best.

Comment: Keep in mind the if you are overwriting existing data the new data will likely need to be the exact same size.

Comment: isnt there a difference between opening it and opening it in append mode?  doesnt one mode just replace whats in the file previously?

Comment: If you are overwriting the entire file then there shouldn't be a problem but if you are overwriting data in the middle of it you need to make sure the new data is the same size (or possibly padded with spaces if it's smaller)

Comment: im reading all the data in as arrays and then writing it back out to the file.  And then the other files i want to add a line to the end of what i have

Answer (score 0):

I can think of these two handy functions.

You may wish to `typedef` some types.

```
/*Read CSV using a vector of vector of string */
std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >  loadCSV(std::istream &input){
  std::string csvLine;
  std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > data;

  while( std::getline(input, csvLine) ){
    std::istringstream csvStream(csvLine);
    std::vector<std::string> csvRow;
    std::string csvCol;

    while( std::getline(csvStream, csvCol, ',') )
      csvRow.push_back(csvCol);
    data.push_back(csvRow);
  }
  return data;
}

/*Modify Data by accessing  elements of data[row][col]*/
/*Add new data using push_back ref. loadCsv function */

/* Finally update */
 void saveCSV(std::ostream &output,const std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >& data){
  if(!data.size())
    return;
  std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >::const_iterator i=data.begin();
  for(; i != data.end(); ++i){
    std::vector<std::string> row =*i;
        if(!row.size())
            continue;
    std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator j=row.begin();
    output<<*(j++);
    for(;i != row.end();++j)
        output<<','<<*j;
    output<<std::endl;
  }
}
```